# Problem in VersionEdit4.Reconcile4 method

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I had an standalone application in which i am getting all the available versions in the database. Based on user filter he selects multiple versions and reconcile it.

```
 if (pVersionEdit4.Reconcile4(pVesrion.VersionInfo.Parent.VersionName, true, false, false, false) == true)
```

I am iterating user selected versions and generating conflict report.
But the previous one is **Row level** conflict check. But i want to check **column level**. For that my code changed to

```
if (pVersionEdit4.Reconcile4(pVesrion.VersionInfo.Parent.VersionName, true, false, false, true) == true)
```

But i am getting exception message **Failed Security**. Is any where i am missing.